# What to install and how to run an executable file on Mac?

Tags: c, terminal, clang, executable

So I'm in terminal, and have a directory called CAPTURE on my desktop, I'm trying to run a program called 'testme'. I read that you need to have build-essential installed but I think that's only on Linux systems and I'm on a Mac so it wasn't necessary because it's already built in (I think). So, I navigated from ~ with:

```
cd Desktop/CAPTURE
```

Then, I tried running a bunch of different commands that I found while looking on the internet:

```
./testme
```

which returned zsh: exec format error: ./testme

```
xcode-select --install
```

which installed properly and I thought I could run the ./testme command but I got the same error as before. Then I tried navigating to the directory again and used

```
chmod +x ./testme
./testme
```

which also did not work. I've never run executables before so I really have no familiarity with these commands so they might be super wrong. If anyone can help me run the file properly, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Seems that your program is interpreted as a shell command : is it binary or some kind of shell and in this case you need to know if it is zsh, bash, sh,csh, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is tagged as C and Clang, and you are talking about `build-essential`, I will assume that you are attempting to build an application from source code.

Instead of `build-essential`, in macOS, you need Xcode. The Xcode CLI tools will work if the application is text-only or Curses, but you will need the entire Xcode IDE for any graphical application.

If running `./testme` is telling you `Executable format error` is probably because it's a prebuilt executable, very likely a Linux ELF executable that will not run in macOS.

My suggestion is to try to build the software. Most C applications will build if you run `make` inside the directory. `make` is installed by default by Xcode. Other applications may need a third-party build system, such as CMake, but I do not know if that's the case.

Comment: I tried running just 'make' and pressing enter inside the directory but I got the following error back 'make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.'

Comment: I see that your application is not using `make`. What files do you see in the directory? Because I have no clue if it's source code, a prebuilt application (in which case you can use `qemu` to run it, but you'll need to install `qemu` yourself), or it's an Xcode project... every option is different.

Comment: The files are the following: BUILD, common.h, ENABLE_CORE_DUMPS, sock_test, sock_test.c, sock.c, sock.o, STORE, store.c, testme, utils.c, utils.o, and sock_test.dSYM...the files that executables are BUILD, ENABLE_CORE_DUMPS, sock_test, STORE, and testme

Comment: No Makefile, no CMakeLists.txt, no build system at all... what kind of program is that? Just another idea: try executing the `BUILD` file, or maybe the `BUILD` file has some instructions inside.